# How to check calling (carrier) signal IOS

Tags: ios

I'm searching how to test the calling signal (if there phone is available to make a call or not. Not the internet or cellular connection, just the calling signal).

Is it possible ? I found for internet and cellular connection but not for calling signal.

Comment: [How to measure carrier's signal streng](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4955390/1031955). I hope this help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accurately reading of iPhone signal strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604273/accurately-reading-of-iphone-signal-strength)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring cellular signal strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength)