# Is there a way to get Signal Strength from Iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, signal-strength

Is there a way to get Signal strength from Iphone using wifi ? 
I know that Public API's do not allow. Istumbler allows it. But it is closed.

With the Private API's is it possible ? I do not want to keep on app store, so I do not mind that.

Would the code for that be available ?

Thanks for that.

I found one code for that :

```
int getSignalStrength()
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
    CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
    if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");  
    int result = CTGetSignalStrength();
    dlclose(libHandle); 
    return result;
}
```

But I dont know what I should pass in "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony".

I have never used IOS development. But I want to run this and test. Can anyone help me what I should do ?

How I should keep the code ?

Comment: It's definitely possible with private APIs - there's an app in thee Cydia (jailbreak) store called "Signal" that lists all the details of the towers that are in view, RSSI, associated tower, etc.

Comment: How can I get the code for that app ?

Comment: Buy a copy and disassemble it / look at what it links to? It's being sold for $5 so they're probably not giving away the code.

Comment: I have edited. Can you please have a look at the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accurately reading of iPhone signal strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604273/accurately-reading-of-iphone-signal-strength)

Answer (score 2):

You can only achieve this with private API calls. There is a list on [google code](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions%20google%20code) with all the functions related to 802.11 devices. Apple80211GetInfoCopy should be the one you're looking for.

But remember that you will not get this into the AppStore...

Comment: I have edited. Can you please have a look at the code

Comment: This goes very much into basics. First of all you should read the documentation on how to add frameworks to your project ([in a nutshell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337890/how-to-add-an-existing-framework-in-xcode-5)). Then import the class with `#import <CoreTelephony/CoreTelephony>` and you should be all set.

Comment: Broken Google Code link.