# Is it possible to detect WIFI network type on iOS?

Tags: ios, networking, wifi, hardware

I'm working on measuring network performance and need to be able to differentiate between various WIFI network standards in the data my app(s) collect. I already do this for cellular with the new CTTelephony API features in iOS 7.0+ but there doesn't seem to be anything for WIFI. (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html)

Specifically, I'd like to record the networking standard (802.11a/b/g/n/ac, etc) as well as the frequency used (2.4Ghz/5Ghz) and channel number.

Is there anything on iOS (even at a very low level) that will allow me to record this info?

Comment: Were you able to get Signal Strength and celular network frequency using that iOS API?

Comment: Nope! Reading signal strength is undocumented/unsupported by Apple, though there are definitely ways of getting your hands on it. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604273/accurately-reading-of-iphone-signal-strength