# How to detect carrier is available or not in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, carrier

I have done most of all the things to get my phone carrier availability. I got signal strength by using `CTGetSignalStrength()` and SIM status by `CTSIMSupportGetSIMStatus();`.

But it always returns **kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusReady**. Now if lost my network connection then it also returns same status as **kCTSIMSupportSIMStatusReady**.

So, is  there any method to get notify for lost of any signal in iphone? My app doesn't require internet connections.

Comment: Is this app for app store?

Comment: Yes, this is for app store.

Comment: App store won't accept for getting signal strength and sim status. There's none clear document for do this. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604273/accurately-reading-of-iphone-signal-strength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use Reachability (included in AFNetworking)

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    // in this case there is no internet connection
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    // in this case there is WiFi connection
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    // in this case there 3G connection, WCDMA-umts
}
```

Do you need to check the difference between WCDMA-UMTS, GPRS, GSM?

Comment: No, i want to just check my sim is in coverage area or not. And also wants to get status of my carrier signal.

Comment: You can check if you have internet and then you can check the transport layer associated to your connection (3G,GSM,EDGE,EDGE+,...). A workaround would be like that and you can make it in the way Ive told you.