# What's the difference between result of CTGetSignalStrength and the number of Field Test Mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wireless

I want to get the cellular signal strength of my iPhone. I have already read lots of answers from stackoverflow. Many people said that we can use an undocumented API CTGetSignalStrength to get what I want.

***First way.***
e.g. [Accurately reading of iPhone signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604273/accurately-reading-of-iphone-signal-strength)
Just like this:

```
-(int) getSignalStrength
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
    CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
    if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");
    int result CTGetSignalStrength();
    dlclose(libHandle);
    return result;
}
```

***Second way***
On the other hand, many website said we can see the signal strength of dBm with so called Field Test Mode.
e.g. http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/20/field-test-mode-iphone-signal-strength-numbers/
We can change the signal indicator of the left-up corner into actual number in dBm.

I have made a little app to test both way. And I found that both of them varied when I got to different places. In detail, when I got into a lift the left-up number varied from -90dBm to -120dBm(***First way***), while the other varied from 26 to 7(***Second way***).

So, I was wondering what's the relation and difference between them. Which one is right?

Comment: Do not use undocumented API . You won't pass Apple's App approval.

Comment: Thanks. I forget to say that I'm not going to deliver this app on Apple's shop.